# Llenar select a partir de una lista con JS

Tags: javascript, select

Tengo esta function en `JS` que cuando entra al `Console.log(lista)`  me trae mi `array` con mis datos de esta manera:

```
0: {id:"XXXXX", nombre:"XXXX"}
...
```

--

```
function CargarPersonas() {
    console.log("Entre");
    var combo = document.getElementById('persona')

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/persona/GETpersonas',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (lista)
        {
             console.log(lista);
        });

}
```

Como le hago para cargar mi `select` con el nombre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una forma de llenar un `select` es con el uso de `document.createElement`, para eso claro tiene que esta anteriormente definido tu `select` non un `id` asignado.

```js
const newOptions = [{id:1, nombre:'option1'}, {id:2, nombre:'option2'}, {id:3, nombre:'option2'}];

function llenarSelect(list){
  const select =  document.getElementById('mySelect');
  
  list.forEach(e=>{
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text=e.nombre;
      option.value=e.id;
      select.appendChild(option);
  })
}

llenarSelect(newOptions);
```

```html
<select id='mySelect'>
  <option>Opciones</option>
</select>
```

En este caso sería unicamente mandar a llamar `llenarSelect()` en `.done` algo como:

```
.done(llenarSelect);
```